# Angular child component event from parent fires multiple times

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a click event (updateExpanded) on my parent, when clicked I fire and event off that goes to the child. the child then subscribes to this event. The problem is that the event gets called 4 times. I have tried everything I could find but just cant seem to see why it gets fired so often when it should only get fired once.

I need to load data in my child component when my parent component gets expanded.

Parent TS

```
@Output()
isExpandedEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();

 updateExpanded(id: string) {
        this.isExpandedEvent.emit(id);
        console.log(id + " parent opened");
    }

ngOnDestroy() {
        if (this.isExpandedEvent) {
            this.isExpandedEvent.unsubscribe();
        }
    }
```

Parent HTML

```
<ngx-planned-maintenance-detail [model]="plannedMaintenanceRecurring" [index]="i" [expandedEventEmitter]="isExpandedEvent">
                </ngx-planned-maintenance-detail>
```

.........

Child TS

```
 @Input()
  expandedEventEmitter = new EventEmitter<string>();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.expandedEventEmitter.subscribe(data => {
        if (data) {
             console.log("detail complete");
        }
     });
  }

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.expandedEventEmitter.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Parent is called once, detail called 4 times as seen below
[image]

Comment: The `[index]="i"` seems to indicate it shows multiple of the same components. Could this be the cause?

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are binding an observable (the `EventEmitter`) to a property. There are 2 issues here.

1. `EventEmitter` is **NOT** the correct way to communicate information ***from*** parent ***to*** child. It's used for the other way around.
2. If you aren't controlling the change detection strategy, the observables/functions bound to a property might be fired multiple times than expected.

If you look at the [`EventEmitter`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/event_emitter.ts#L64) source, it's a simple interface extension of RxJS [`Subject`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject). So what you could do in this instance is to create a [singleton service](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services) that will hold the shared information between the components directly using a RxJS `Subject`.

shared.service.ts

```js
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class SharedService {
  isExpanded = new Subject<any>();

  constructor() { }

  pushIsExpanded(value: any) {
    this.isExpanded.next(value);
  }

  getIsExpanded() {
    return this.isExpanded.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Now you could inject this singleton in both the components and use the shared data.

parent.component.ts

```js
export class ParentComponent {
  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) { }

  updateExpanded(id: string) {
    this.sharedService.pushIsExpanded(id);
  }
}
```

child.component.ts

```js
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class ChildComponent {
  const completed$ = new Subject<any>();

  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sharedService.getIsExpanded().pipe(
      takeUntil(this.completed$)
    ).subscribe(
      data => {
        if (data) {
          console.log("detail complete");
        }
     }
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.completed$.next();
    this.completed$.complete();
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a really nice solution that I do like however I sit with a strange issue. My accordion currently has 7 items in it. The initial click in the parent is fine and fires once but it seems to send this event to all the children...... How do this event only fire for the detail component related the parent component that has been clicked?

Comment: That isn't strange. That's the nature of the RxJS `Subject`, it's a multicast observable. If you need to communicate a value from the parent to a specific child, you could make do only with a `@Input` variable and yet still avoiding a observable. But you need to provide more implementation details. Specifically it'd be helpful to show the data structure you're trying to pass to the child components.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Essentially I am building an dynamic accordion. then once you click to expand it I want to call the api to actually fill it with data. This is so I dont make e.g 30 api calls. I am not on my home pc now but will send some more info later....So the accordion (parent) gets clicked. this should pass the parent id to the specific child to fire the api call in the child. The accordion item is the parent and then houses 1 child component.

Answer (score 0):

use a `ViewChild` to send click events to a child.

use `EventEmitter` to send click events from the child up to the parent.

Comment: A viewchild causes circular dependancy

Comment: I meant use viewChild INSTEAD of eventEmitter.